# Distinguishing between two weighted dice (or discrete distributions)

Tags: probability, sampling

In a bag, there are two dice, each with sides weighted differently. I know the weighting of the two dice. I reach into the bag and pick one out with equal probability. I want to know how many rolls it will take (as a function of the two distributions) for me to know, with high probability, which die I am rolling. The closer the

Put differently, I believe I am trying to find the sample complexity of an algorithm that distinguishes between two different discrete distributions. I believe I have a way to do this for two weighted coins (using a tail bound on the binomial distribution). What I've found is that if I one coin has Pr[H] = 0.5 and one has Pr[H] = p > 0.5, after $n \geq -\frac{2p}{(p - \frac{1}{2})^2} \ln \epsilon$ coin flips, I can guess which type of coin it is with accuracy $1 - \epsilon$.

I'm pretty sure there should be a simple reduction, but I can't find a good explanation online, perhaps because I lack the proper vocabulary (I come from a CS background and don't know stats/probability super well).

Comment: I don't think that there's a general answer to your question. The "closest" the two distributions are, the larger number of rolls it will require in order to make a correct guess with high probability. For example take $P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=P(4)=20\%$ on both dice, then $P_1(5)=P_2(6)=4.9999\%$ and $P_1(6)=P_2(5)=5.0001\%$. In a similar manner, you can make those two distributions closer and closer to each other, which will require you a larger number of rolls in order to pass the threshold that you define for a good enough guess.

Comment: Hi @barakmanos, I edited the question to clarify-- I'm not looking for a specific number, but rather a function that takes the distributions as input, and gives a number of samples to take to get a good estimate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that'll answer fully your question, but to distinguish between a fair coin and a $\varepsilon$-biased one (for $\varepsilon$ being less than some absolute constant), you need $\Omega(1/\varepsilon^2)$ independent coin tosses (to be right with probability greater than, say, $2/3$). This is a ''folklore result'' and can be derived from the total variation distance between two Binomial distributions, see e.g. Fact 1 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3835.pdf).

For the complexity of distinguishing between two discrete distributions, see e.g. [Optimal Algorithms for Testing Closeness of Discrete Distributions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3946) by Chan et al. and the references therein.

More generally, the [following article](http://xrds.acm.org/article.cfm?aid=2331052) (an introduction to property testing of distributions) by R. Rubinfeld may be of interest to you. Some [relevant slides](http://www.iliasdiakonikolas.org/stoc-distribution-estimation.html) are also available from a workshop (STOC '14): look at the first talk of Session 1.

Comment: This is helpful and close to what I want but not exactly. I'll check the paper and references and see if it gives me the answer!